# Hibernate Criteria for "in subselect"

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, subquery, criteria

I'm trying to do something like this, but using `Criteria` instead of `HQL`:

```
select user from User where user in (
    select user from UserDomain where domain.id = "XXX"
)
```

User being an entity having a `one-to-many` relationship to the join table UserDomain.
The point here is simply to find Users that are linked to a `Domain` having id = "XXX".

This seems like it should be very simple... but I'm having no luck so far turning up any useful docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it.  Turns out it wasn't so hard after all... once you know!

```
criteria = criteria.createCriteria(User.USER_DOMAINS).add(Restrictions.eq(UserDomain.DOMAIN, domain));
```

Yep, there is was, staring me right in the face in the Javadoc:
http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html

Answer (score 28):

The subquery is very useful in cases, that you need to search the User, having *one-to-many* UserDomains. In that case, the `WHERE UserId IN (subquery)` brings big advanatage: we are still working with a flat `User` table/entity... so we can do the proper paging.

Here is the documentation [15.8. Detached queries and subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries)

The draft could be: subquery:

```
DetachedCriteria userSubquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserDomain.class, "ud")
    // Filter the Subquery
    .add(Restrictions.eq(UserDomain.DOMAIN, domain))
    // SELECT The User Id  
    .setProjection( Projections.property("ud.userId") );
```

And the main query:

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(User.class, "u")
    .add( Subqueries.propertyIn("u.id", userSubquery) );
```

Now we have a query, which could be used for paging

Comment: On small correction, I think you meant ".add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", userSubquery))". Your example causes some cryptic class cast exceptions.

Comment: As a side note: you may encounter 'Class Cast Exception' as I did if you try to change `Subqueries.propertyIn("u.id", userSubquery)` to `Subqueries.eq("u.id", userSubquery)` - don't do that even if there is a single match for a subquery.

Answer (score 3):

In clauses usualy can be transformed into join. Tyr this:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class, "u");
c.createAlias("u.userDomain", "ud"); // inner join by default
c.add(Restrictions.le("ud.id", 1));
```

Comment: No, there is no "u.userDomain" relationship.  User.userDomains is a to-many relationship to the join table UserDomain.